# Bind a function with the injected html in angular 7

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I wanted to bind a function into the injected html at run time using innerHTML. 
My component

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<div [innerHtml]="myHTML | safeHtml"></div>`,
  styleUrls: ['/my-app.css'], encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom
})
export class MyApp implements OnInit {
 myHTML = `<button (click)="clickMe()" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">+</button>`
 constructor() {}
  
  clickMe() {
    console.log("Function is binded using the inner html tag")
  }
}
```

I tried but it does not seem to work. I am not sure if I have missed something. Any help is appreciated

Comment: You' might want to check **[`dynamic component loader`](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader)** for this.

Answer (score -1):

Implement `safeHtml` pipe; it does not come out of box:

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'safeHtml'
})
export class SafeHtmlPipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }

  transform(value: string): any {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value);
  }
}
```